# display information of each records in erlang

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have this tables :

```
-record(person, {id, firstname, lastname}).
```

and it contains this values :

```
13  asma   chabani
14  nawel  jirard
15  ahme   bahri
```

I want to display the firstname and lastname of each record :

I try with :

```
test()->
    Match=#person{_ = '_'}, %Will match all records
    Fun =
      fun() ->
        List = mnesia:match_object(Match),
        lists:foreach(fun(X) ->
                        M=X#person.fistname,
                        H=X#person.lastname,
                        io:format("~s~n",[M]),
                        io:format("~s~n",[H])
                      end,
                      List)
      end.
```

but it displays this error :

```
model:test().
#Fun<model.186.53419390>
```

Comment: `#Fun<model.186.53419390>` - this is not an error, this is function that you defined `Fun = fun()...`

Answer (score 2):

Have you forgot mnesia:transaction(Fun) in the end? Or just Fun().